# Failure/Error: post :create, game_session: {} ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

We're trying to run a simple post:create in RSpec, but we're getting the error:

Failure/Error: post :create, game_session: {}
     ArgumentError:
       When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

```
  describe "starting a new test with GameSessionsController#create" do
    it "creates a new game session" do
      login_user
      game_session_count = GameSession.count

      post :create # Here is the error

      expect(GameSession.count).to eq( game_session_count + 1 )
      expect(response).to redirect_to new_game_session_current_question_path
    end
  end
```

Our routes file just contains `resources :game_sessions`, and our controller is as standard.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the relevant controller code too?

Comment: Note: the error message says the line that is erroring contains: `post :create, game_session: {} ` not just `post :create` - are you sure you're showing us the right line of code?